# Return an object on calling a class instance without parentheses

Tags: python, pandas, class

I have multiple databases that I am connecting to follows:

```
class DB:
    def __init__(self, database):
        conn_str = ...
        try:
            self.engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(conn_str)
            self.conn = self.engine.connect()
            print('yay')
        except Exception as e:
            print('\n Something is wrong: \n', e)

    def __call__(self):
        return self.engine

db1 = DB(some_url)
```

From here, calling `db1.engine` or `db1()` will return `Engine(mssql+pymssql://...)`
What I would like is for `db1` (no parentheses) to give me the same result: an object of the type `sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine`.

This should be possible!  Consider that Pandas `pd.DataFrame()` is a class. You can call a class instance and have it return a DataFrame without parentheses, like so:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame()
type(x)
```

`pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`

I tried going through pandas source code, but could not figure out how they do it.

Comment: "You can call a class instance and have it return a DataFrame without parentheses, like so:" um, you called it with parentheses? `pd.DataFrame**()**` Note, `pd.DataFrame()` is an *instance* of the class `pd.DataFrame` Anyway, you cannot *call* something without parentheses.

Comment: The PO means that calling the class name `DB(some_url)` should return an instance of `Engine`, which is another class.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame` is just an alias (reference) to `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`. You seem to have misunderstood pandas.

Comment: @gdlmx [Pandas source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.24.2/pandas/core/frame.py#L290-L7950) -- DataFrame is a class.  We define x as an instance of class DataFrame, `x=pd.DataFrame()`.  And then we call it just with `x`, not `x()`.  I want to do the same with `db1`.  Does this make sense?

Comment: That *is* what you are doing with `db1 = DB(some_url)`

Comment: Honestly, I struggle to think why you need the class `DB` at all in this case. Seems like you only need a plain old factory function, and return tuple of <engine, connection>

Comment: For convenience and flexibility. How do you prefer to look at a DataFrame -- with a `df` or `df()`?  I have several databases to work with at the same time, and I need to pass the engine into Pandas.  I want to be able to pass simply db1, db2 etc, not db1() or db2.engine.  And I want it to remain a class and retain the option of defining class methods.